# append data in existing excel file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am copying gridview value which has more than 20 columns and 500+ rows in clipboard and copying that value into excel file.

```
    Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim aWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    aWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add()
    excelApp.Visible = False
    Dim strWorkSheetName As String = "MyData"
    Dim aWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    aWorkSheet = aWorkbook.Sheets.Add()


    aWorkSheet.name = TextBox1.Text

    aWorkSheet.Activate()

    Dim intRows As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count
    Dim strRangeString As String = "C4:G" & intRows.ToString



    'Open the existing Template
    Dim _Tpath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Template.xlsx"
    aWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(_Tpath)

    Dim alpha As String
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim cell As String
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        alpha = Convert.ToChar(65 + count)
        num = Convert.ToInt32(7)
        cell = Convert.ToString(alpha & "7")

        aWorkSheet.Range(cell).Value = col.HeaderText.ToString
        count = count + 1
    Next

    For row As Integer = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
        For col As Integer = 0 To dt2.Columns.Count - 1
            alpha = Convert.ToChar(65 + col)
            num = Convert.ToInt32(8 + row)
            cell = Convert.ToString(alpha & num)

            aWorkSheet.Range(cell).Value = dt2(row)(col).ToString
        Next
    Next
```

but now i want to paste that clipboard value into an existing excel file(used as template) on a specific position suppose from 7th row and above. i have written some code where values are pasting cell by cell and it is taking lot of time. is there any other way to paste gridview value in an existing excel file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many columns and rows are in your `GridView` then you can use [Worksheet.Paste()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.paste%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) using a `Range` that covers an appropriately sized area.  So if your `GridView` has 5 columns and 500 rows and you want your selection to start 2 rows down and 2 columns in, you could do

```
aWorksheet.Paste(aWorksheet.Range(aWorksheet.Cells(2,2),aWorksheet.Cells(502,7)))
```